Does anybody know this integral expression?
I stumbled upon the following integral, which is a low dimensional case of a minimization problem I currently investigate.
$$F(V) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|W+\nabla\times V)|^2+|\nabla\times(W+\nabla\times V))|^2dx$$
where $W$ is a fixed vector field that is divergence free and $V$ is another vector field, both compactly supported on $\mathbb{R}^3$ or periodic in all components in which case we would just integrate over the smallest period rectangle (I do not know if there is a term describing what I mean here, but it should be clear).
Of course by Poincares lemma one has that in the non-periodic case a minimizer $V$ is the negative vector potential of $W$, since then $F(V)=0$.
It would be really helpful, if somebody could give an interpretation of this integral or point to some physical object this integral corresponds to.

Among the same line of reasoning you already presented: the integral could be the expression for the energy in an EM field at a given frequency. With the spatial coordinates scaled and $c=1$ to make all constants disappear, it is the integral of $|\bf{B}|^2+|\bf{E}|^2$. But this works only at one frequency and in a source free region, because then we can scale things to get $-i\,\bf{E}=\bf{\nabla}\times\bf{B}$. And because the 90 degree phase difference in time it would be energy "averaged over one period". Despite all that, for a time-periodic field this might serve to make sense of the integral...
And the minimization problem then asks what field you have to add to a given field $({\bf B},i\,\bf{E})$=$(\bf{W},\ \bf{\nabla}\times\bf{W})$, to minimize the energy, when this additional field is expressed in terms of a vector potential ($\bf{V}$).
What would be the use of that all? Perhaps just for studying gauge invariance. The minimization would show the degeneracy in solutions ($\bf{V}$ would not be unique, you can add any gradient). And then maybe demonstrating ways to get around that by adding gauge-fixing things to the integral? (I'm of course just trying to assume this is all part of some analysis where this would have a purpose.)

I like this answer a lot, but I will not yet close the question in hope somebody has another interpretation. Thank you.
